# asp.net mvc 5 how to hash the password

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

this the controller:

```
   [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "UserID,UserName,UserEmail,UserPass")] User user)
         {
            user.UserPass= "12345999";
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Users.Add(user);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

        return View(user);
    }
```

1- how I can post the user.UserPass from the form

2- how to Hash it

thanks in advance

Comment: https://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity

Comment: [Salted Password Hashing - Doing it Right](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm) But why are you wanting to do this manually instead of using [Identity](https://www.asp.net/identity)

Comment: here I am doing my self with the identity, so I just need to solve this controller

Comment: because I want to learn the real action behind the framework and check my own style

Comment: 1. from a form you post the model (username, email, pass), 2. idenitity hash itself your password. 3. Rephrase your question

Comment: Ok, then use a hasing mechanism over the saved password, and when you are checking the login model pass compare the hashed sent pass with saved pass

Comment: Rule number one of web design, if you can avoid handling passwords yourself, do so.

Comment: Here is how to hash password in Asp.net Mvc https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/data-protection/consumer-apis/password-hashing.html

Answer (score 0):

You can post your model to Action. Then you can use Sha 256 hashing mechanism  to password before saving data in database. So when you are trying login you should encode  password with Sha 256 and compare hashes.